# Procurando um item no arquivo XML em php

Tags: php, array, xml

Tenho um arquivo xml, e gostaria de trazer para a pagina apenas um item desse arquivo, no caso eu consigo trazer todos os items de uma vês só através do codigo

```
<?php
    $feed = file_get_contents('https://brasil.elpais.com/rss/brasil/portada_completo.xml');
    $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

     //echo "<pre>"; print_r($rss);
    foreach($rss->channel->item as $noticia) {
        echo '<p><a href="'.$noticia->link.'" title="'. $noticia->title .'">'.$noticia->title.''.$noticia->description.'</a></p>';
    }       

?>
```

No caso eu não quero apresentar todos os itens , quero apenas uma parte especifica do XML, que se encontra no meio do array gerado, o print do array gerado é esse: [image: array]

no caso quero trazer o array [item][6], só que não estou conseguindo fazer essa localização, e gostaria também de perguntar alguma forma de integrar xmls, no caso de eu tiver mais de 1 gostaria de intercalar na pagina as tags selecionadas. Se puderem me ajudar fico grato.

No caso mostrar a primeira tag item do primeiro arquivo xml, em seguida mostrar a primeira tag item do segundo arquivo xml, dps mostrar a quarta tag item do primeiro arquivo xml e assim por diante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplesmente faça isso (lembre-se o indice começa a contar do zero, então 0 é o primeiro item, 1 é o segundo, etc):

```
$rss->channel->item[6];
```

Exemplo para pegar o titulo:

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents('https://brasil.elpais.com/rss/brasil/portada_completo.xml');
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

$item_especifico = $rss->channel->item[6];

echo 'Titulo:', $item_especifico->title;
```

Note que para pegar `@attributes` em SimpleXml deve usar o método `->attributes()`, assim:

```
<?php
$feed = file_get_contents('https://brasil.elpais.com/rss/brasil/portada_completo.xml');
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

$item_especifico = $rss->channel->item[6];
$enclosure = $item_especifico->enclosure->attributes();

echo 'Titulo:', $item_especifico->title, '<br>';
echo 'Imagem:', $enclosure->url, '<br>';
echo 'Peso da imagem:', $enclosure->length, '<br>';
```

Comment: Otimo super funcionou, queria tirar mais uma duvida, dentro da tag item, existe uma tag [enclosure] que é um array com 2 atributos dessa forma:

[enclosure] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
     [@attributes] => Array ( [url] => https://ep00.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2018/07/11/actualidad/1531322308_202368_1531325055_miniatura_normal.jpg
    [length] => 26887
    [type] => image/jpeg
)
[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object... ai com os mesmo elementos que o de cima, só muda a tag [url] .

e queria exibir o indice 1 da tag [enclosure] e ele não me mostra nada.

Comment: @BrunoClementin editei a resposta e coloquei um exemplo de como pegar os atributos do enclosure

Comment: demais @GuilhermeNascimento, sou novo no mundo da programação e você foi de grande ajuda, fico extremamente grato pela ajuda. 

só mais uma coisa, no caso ele me mostra examente o http da url, e não a imagem em si, sabe como resolvo para mostrar a imagem ?

Comment: @BrunoClementin assim `echo '<img src="', $enclosure->url,'">';`

Comment: Sensacional muito obrigado, namastê!